# Flipping a Texture in Libgdx Java

Tags: java, libgdx

I am trying to figure out how to flip a `Texture` in libgdx using Java. I can't find any methods of doing this and I can't just do some code to flip the `Texture` itself. Is there any way that I can flip the texture some way in libgdx?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can make a Sprite object and when you initialize it, you can pass in the `Texture` object. Then you can call methods such as rotate, flip, etc. Here is a code example

```
    Texture tex = new Texture("path");
    Sprite sprite = new Sprite(tex);
    sprite.flip(true, false);
```

true as the first parameter for flipping over x-axis and false for y-axis, which is what you are looking for in your specific example.

Comment: This will not work if I want to paste my `Texture` onto a `Model` right?